# jQuery Cropit set result width and height instead of cropit-preview width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit.

Here is the problem:

1. I don't want to use cropit-preview width and height for the result cropped image.
2. I want my image crop to 1900x1080, but I dont want to show the preview (cropbox) 1900*1080.

I've tried:

```
<div class="cover-editor">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">

    <div style="width:400; height:225px"> // I put this so the preview won't bigger than this but still no luck
        <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="image-size-label">
        Resize image
    </div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="cover" class="cover"/>
</div>
```

If I set

```
 $('.cover-editor').cropit({width: 400, height: 225});
```

the result image will be 400*225.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6cakyxq/

Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried to set?  .cropit-preview {  width: 400px;  height: 225px;}

Comment: ` $('.cover-editor').cropit({width: 400, height: 225});` this code automatically put css to `.cropit-preview`

Comment: ok then create fiddle to understand!!

Comment: @BhumiShah here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e6cakyxq/

Comment: @BhumiShah What I try to achieve is the crop box 400*225, but when I crop it the result become for example 1920*1080.